# How can I pipe the output of *all* entered shell commands into another? (e.g. pipe everything into 'lolcat')

Tags: unix, shell, ruby, pipe, stdout

Good Afternoon,

(OS X user)

I am specifically trying to pipe the output of every shell command I type into the ruby gem 'lolcat' (which makes the output to the terminal rainbow colored).

Is there a way to do this without explicitly aliasing command individually? I was thinking perhaps there might be a way to pipe anything before the return key is pressed , but I am not sure how to do this.

Your assistance is appreciated, as I am tired of looking at just one color in my terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can redirect stdout in your shell:

```
exec 1> >(lolcat)
```

## BUT

if `lolcat` sends its own output to stdout, you're bound to run into problems. This might work

```
exec 1> >(lolcat >&2)
```

Comment: Thanks Glenn! How would I incorporate this into my .bashrc, alias the exec command?

Comment: I'm not sure that's working, so I'd explicitly turn it on (don't make it the default behaviour): `lol() { exec 1> >(lolcat); }` and to turn it off: `unlol() { exec 1> /dev/stdout; }`

Comment: I'm sure there will be some issues (I've noticed when turned on programs like 'nano' will not work), but this is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Comment: I feel like you want to shoot yourself in the foot and I just gave you the gun. Good luck.

Comment: At the risk of accidentally doing something I'll regret (which now seems to be much higher than usual), I'm leaving it off and just aliasing ls for now.

Comment: Did not work for me. `sh: syntax error near unexpected token `>'`

Comment: The process substitution `>(...)` is a bash feature. Cannot use plain `sh`

Answer (score 1):

You could do this:

```
bash | lolcat
```

this enters into bash and whatever command you run will be rainbow

Answer (score 0):

I made a shell extension for the world's fastest website generator that I make called [Nift](https://nift.dev). It has an easter egg where you can turn on lolcat output for most things with `lolcat.on` (after starting the shell with eg. `nift sh`). You will even get rainbow output when pressing tab to get possible completion options, I doubt you get that with any other suggested solutions.

The shell extension is for [f++](https://nift.dev/docs/f++.html) which is the in-built scripting language, which has [these](https://nift.dev/docs/fns.html) functions and [these](https://nift.dev/docs/types.html) types available. But anything it doesn't recognise is run as a system call using the (probably primary/default) shell on your machine (hence calling it a shell extension in REPL shell mode).

Nift will look for a version of lolcat installed on your machine and otherwise use an in-built version of it which should be the world's fastest (it's near identical to my c++ implementation [lolcat-cc](https://github.com/n-ham/lolcat-cc) which is the world's fastest). I highly recommend installing lolcat-cc (or another version of lolcat) on top of Nift though as otherwise you are frequently running the ~5mb Nift binary for basically all system calls, instead of a <1mb binary for lolcat.

f++ is somewhat of an interesting scripting language as well. Take [this](https://pastebin.com/5FM7Hzef) script for example which creates and deletes 100k empty text files. On my machine this runs in ~3.5 seconds whereas [this](https://pastebin.com/RTXXEHBg) Bash script doing essentially the same thing takes more like 3 minutes!! Some of the cool things you might already notice from that f++ script is you can expand variables inside strings, you can define variables with types, you can expand variables in to multiple parameters with function calls, you can have LOTS more than 10k input parameters for function calls (should be able to have millions!).

You can find some more information about the Nift REPLs (including shortcuts for different platforms) [here](https://nift.dev/docs/interactive.html).

If you need to define shell variables (not through f++ but the underlying shell) then you will need to do blocks of code using the sys/system function. You can also do blocks of code for Lua(JIT) and ExprTk similarly as they are both embedded in to Nift. You can use both Lua and ExprTk with accessing/modifying f++ variables as well..

So to get this shell (extension). Install Nift through a package manager or clone, make and install off GitHub. Enter `nift sh` in to your terminal to start the Nift f++ shell extension, then enter `lolcat.on` to turn on rainbow output.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions. If the same information really answers both questions, then one question (usually the newer one) should be closed as a duplicate of the other. You can indicate this by [voting to close it as a duplicate](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/close-questions) or, if you don't have enough reputation for that, [raise a flag](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to indicate that it's a duplicate. Otherwise tailor your answer to this question and don't just paste the same answer in multiple places.